# Obfuscated Integer Notation

Tags: code-golf, math, number, number-theory

**Edit: I will be posting a newer version of this question on `meta-golf` soon. Stay tooned!**

**Edit #2: I will no longer be updating the challenge, but will leave it open. The `meta-golf` version is available here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106509/obfuscated-number-golf**

## Background:

Most numbers can be written with only 6 different symbols:

- `e` (Euler's Constant)
- `-` (Subtraction, Not Negation)
- `^` (Exponentiation)
- `(`
- `)`
- `ln` (Natural Logarithm)

For example, you could convert the imaginary number `i` using this equation:

```
(e-e-e^(e-e))^(e^(e-e-ln(e^(e-e)-(e-e-e^(e-e)))))
```

## Goal:

Given any integer `k` through any reasonable means, output the shortest representation possible of that number using only those 6 symbols.

## Examples:

```
0 => "e-e"
1 => "ln(e)"
2 => "ln(ee)"
// Since - cannot be used for negation, this is not a valid solution: 
// ln(e)-(-ln(e))
-1 => "e-e-ln(e)"
```

## Notes:

- Ending parenthesis count towards the total amount of characters.
- `ln(` only counts as 1 character.
- Everything else counts as 1 character.
- `n^0=1`
- Order of operations apply
- Parenthesis multiplying is acceptable, e.g. `(2)(8)=16`, `2(5)=10`, and `eln(e)=e`.
- `ln e` is not valid, you must do `ln(e)`

Comment: I think that formula (`ln(ee...e)`) is the best way to portray positives. Edit: no, its not. `ln(e^(ln(eeeee)ln(eeee)))` is better for 20

Comment: @JulianLachniet love the idea, would like to see the first 10-20 terms of the sequence requested though. Maybe put up an example for -10 to 10 for clarification. WheatWizard has already poked a couple holes, with those holes the objective criteria of "shortest possible" is hard to determine without concrete examples.

Comment: Not sure about some of the higher ones, especially 20.

Comment: Can I output mathematica's symbol for e instead of the ascii character 'e'?

Comment: Yes, it's still counted as a byte

Comment: This form: `ln(ee...e)` takes `n + 3` characters. This: `ln(e^((A1)(A2)...(AK)))` takes `6 + combined character count of A1-K` where `A1 * A2 * ... AK == n`

Comment: `ln(eeee)^ln(ee)` is a shorter than `ln(eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee)` for 16

Comment: First of all, this is non-trivial since multiplication can save code. Second, I have not written an optimal program which makes test cases difficult to prove.

Comment: Just a word of suggestion.  I think this might be more fun as a [tag:meta-golf] challenge than as a [tag:code-golf] challenge.  Its really hard to demonstrate that some code always produces the optimal result so it might be better to score answers on how well they golf their output.

Comment: Meta-golf tag has no questions. Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: @JulianLachniet no hyphen sorry.  [tag:metagolf]

Comment: I'm thinking best solution is brute force it.

Comment: `ln(eee)^ln(ee)` is shorter than `ln(eeeeeeeee)` by one character (since `ln(` is one character) making that the lower bound for solutions that are not `ln(eee...)`

Comment: Using prefix is not allowed as it could change the results.

Comment: Can this output any valid representation or the shortest one?

Comment: No. There is a reason for the notation I chose

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. (But I think you mean `eln(e)=e`.)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 402 bytes

```
from itertools import*
from ast import*
from math import*
v,r=lambda x:'UnaryOp'not in dump(parse(x)),lambda s,a,b:s.replace(a,b)
def l(x,y):
    for s in product('L()e^-',repeat=x):
        f=r(r(r(''.join(s),'L','log('),')(',')*('),'^','**')
        g=r(f,'ee','e*e')
        while g!=f:f,g=g,r(g,'ee','e*e')
        try:
            if eval(g)==y and v(g):return g
        except:0
def b(v):
    i=1
    while 1:
        r=l(i,v)
        if r:return r
        i+=1
```

Example usage:

```
>>> b(1)
'log(e)'
>>> b(0)
'e-e'
>>> b(-3)
'e-log(e*e*e)-e'
>>> b(8)
'log(e*e)**log(e*e*e)'
```

Note that although the output format may not reflect it, the code properly counts all lengths according to the question's specifications.

This is a dumb bruteforce through all the possible lengths of strings. Then I use some replacements so that Python can evaluate it. If it's equal to what we want, I also check to exclude unary negative signs by checking the AST.

I'm not very good at golfing in Python, so here's the semi-ungolfed code if anybody wants to help!

```
from itertools import*
from ast import*
from math import*

def valid(ev):
    return 'UnaryOp' not in dump(parse(ev))

def to_eval(st):
    f = ''.join(st).replace('L', 'log(').replace(')(', ')*(').replace('^', '**')
    nf = f.replace('ee', 'e*e')
    while nf != f:
        f, nf = nf, nf.replace('ee', 'e*e')
    return nf

def try_length(length, val):
    for st in product('L()e^-', repeat=length):
        ev = to_eval(st) 
        try:
            if eval(ev) == val and valid(ev):
                return st
        except:
            pass

def bruteforce(val):
    for i in range(11):
        res = try_length(i, val)
        if res:
            print(i, res)
            return res
```

Comment: Instead of indenting with tabs you can indent with spaces for one level of indent and tabs for 2.